# Click on a button in a row in a table

Tags: html, selenium, automation, selenium-ide, buttonclick

I am having a table:

```
<table id="tabmailveille">
<tr><td>
<button onclick="return Ajax(162, {'idc': '125').value,'action': 'ajout'});"><img alt="Add" src="/Images/tableaux/add.png" class="buttonimg"></button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

All I want to do is trying to click the button.

So I tried:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//table[@id='tabmailveille']/tr/td/button[@class='buttonimg']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

It doesn't work. The button is not clicked. What's wrong with the code?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button element is not assigned a class. Image element is. Therefore xpath is incorrect.

Correct XPath:

```
//table[@id='tabmailveille']/tr/td/button/img[@class='buttonimg']
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your helps, I don' t understand, your code seems to be fine, but when i execute it, I got the error: [error] Element //table[@id='tabmailveille']/tr/td/button[img/@class='buttonimg'] not found , extremely strange. <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//table[@id='tabmailveille']/tr/td/button[img/@class='buttonimg']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in this XPath, which was introduced by the editor of my post, not me. I edited the above answer, can you please try again?